# Is my python generator function really lazy?

Tags: python, generator

Simple generator function I made:

```
def myfunc(text):
    for i in text[::-1]:
        yield(i)

for i in myfunc("anytext"):
    print(i)
```

will `text[::-1]` inside generator function will be evaluated first or it will be evaluated lazily (expected from generator function) ?

Comment: It will be evaluated exactly the same as any other time you do string slicing: `str[...]` returns a new string, which you then loop over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text will be reversed before it is iterated over. It can't be any other way; the `for` loop needs the reversed text in order to iterate over it.

To make it truly lazy you'll need to use an index.

```
def myfunc(text):
    for i in range(len(text) - 1, -1, -1):
        yield text[i]
```

In Python 2, use `xrange` in place of `range`.

Of course, you have basically re-implemented the built-in function `reversed()`.

Comment: "It can't be any other way; the for loop needs the reversed text in order to iterate over it." unfortunate wording? You're still using a for loop.

Comment: @viraptor `text[::-1]` needs to be evaluated, and then an iterator made from the result, so yes the "reversed text" does need to be generated in this case **before** the `for` loop can begin  (it would be lazy of course if `str.__getitem__` returned an iterator)

Comment: Well, `text[::-1]` *could* return an iterator instead of a string… so it *can* be another way; it just obviously isn't.

Comment: @deceze I was just adding that!

Comment: @donkopotamus I understand what's happening and what kindall meant. I just think it's a bit unfortunate, potentially confusing wording. I'd drop the "It can't be any other way".